# Shaderc crashes on calling glsl to spv assembly on android

Tags: android, c++, android-ndk, segmentation-fault

I was trying to use shaderc to compile glsl shaders to spir-v during runtime. The library works fine on desktop win32 application, but when I try to move it on android using Visual Studio 2017 it crashes if the shader has not compilation errors. I was testing on NVIDIA shield tablet.

This is one of versions of the code that crashes:

```
void android_main( struct android_app* state )
{
    shaderc::Compiler compiler;
    shaderc::CompileOptions options;
    char test_program[] = "#version 450 \n void main() { gl_Position = vec4(0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f);}";     
    shaderc::AssemblyCompilationResult assembly =
        compiler.CompileGlslToSpvAssembly( test_program, strlen( test_program ),
                                           shaderc_glsl_vertex_shader, "shader", "main", options );

    if( assembly.GetCompilationStatus( ) != shaderc_compilation_status_success )
        LOGI( assembly.GetErrorMessage( ).c_str( ) );

    std::string resultAssembly( assembly.cbegin( ), assembly.cend( ) );
    for( int i = 0; i < resultAssembly.length( ); i++ )
    {
        int newline = resultAssembly.find_first_of( '\n', i );
        newline = newline != -1 ? newline : resultAssembly.length( );
        LOGI( "%s", resultAssembly.substr( i, newline - i ).c_str( ) );
        i = newline;
    }

    compiler.CompileGlslToSpv( test_program, strlen( test_program ),
                               shaderc_glsl_vertex_shader, "shader" );
}
```

With this logcat:

```
08-28 22:36:38.431  5450  5484 F libc    : Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1, fault addr 0x48 in tid 5484 (m.AndroidEngine)
08-28 22:36:38.432  5450  5458 I art     : Starting a blocking GC Instrumentation
08-28 22:36:38.434   183   183 W         : debuggerd: handling request: pid=5450 uid=10154 gid=10154 tid=5484
08-28 22:36:38.548  5487  5487 F DEBUG   : *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** *** ***
08-28 22:36:38.550  5487  5487 F DEBUG   : Build fingerprint: 'nvidia/wx_un_do/shieldtablet:7.0/NRD90M/1928188_904.2811:user/release-keys'
08-28 22:36:38.550  5487  5487 F DEBUG   : Revision: '0'
08-28 22:36:38.551  5487  5487 F DEBUG   : ABI: 'arm'
08-28 22:36:38.552  5487  5487 F DEBUG   : pid: 5450, tid: 5484, name: m.AndroidEngine  >>> com.AndroidEngine <<<
08-28 22:36:38.553  5487  5487 F DEBUG   : signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 1 (SEGV_MAPERR), fault addr 0x48
08-28 22:36:38.553  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     r0 95642fe0  r1 00000002  r2 95ae6428  r3 9564201c
08-28 22:36:38.554  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     r4 95641f60  r5 95642fe0  r6 00000048  r7 956416e0
08-28 22:36:38.555  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     r8 00000002  r9 00000000  sl 00000005  fp fffffcb8
08-28 22:36:38.556  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     ip 0000002e  sp 956416c0  lr 95ae63bb  pc 00000048  cpsr 200f0010
08-28 22:36:38.578  5487  5487 F DEBUG   : 
08-28 22:36:38.578  5487  5487 F DEBUG   : backtrace:
08-28 22:36:38.579  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #00 pc 00000048  <unknown>
08-28 22:36:38.579  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0017b3b9  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZN8libspirv16DiagnosticStreamD2Ev+84)
08-28 22:36:38.579  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00159a2d  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libVkLayer_core_validation.so (spvBinaryParse+5248)
08-28 22:36:38.580  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00194065  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZN8libspirv18FriendlyNameMapperC1EPK13spv_context_tPKjj+124)
08-28 22:36:38.580  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #04 pc 0017a697  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (spvBinaryToText+174)
08-28 22:36:38.580  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #05 pc 0017a463  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZNK8spvtools10SpirvTools11DisassembleEPKjjPSsj+38)
08-28 22:36:38.581  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #06 pc 0017a435  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZNK8spvtools10SpirvTools11DisassembleERKSt6vectorIjSaIjEEPSsj+24)
08-28 22:36:38.581  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #07 pc 0014d1e9  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZN12shaderc_util21SpirvToolsDisassembleENS_8Compiler9TargetEnvERKSt6vectorIjSaIjEEPSs+96)
08-28 22:36:38.581  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #08 pc 0014e013  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZNK12shaderc_util8Compiler7CompileERKNS_12string_pieceE11EShLanguageRKSsPKcRKSt8functionIFS4_PSoS3_EERNS_16CountingIncluderENS0_10OutputTypeESA_PjSI_PNS_18GlslangInitializerE+1246)
08-28 22:36:38.581  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #09 pc 000d34bf  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so
08-28 22:36:38.582  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #10 pc 000d3793  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (shaderc_compile_into_spv_assembly+22)
08-28 22:36:38.582  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #11 pc 000c4167  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZNK7shaderc8Compiler24CompileGlslToSpvAssemblyEPKcj19shaderc_shader_kindS2_S2_RKNS_14CompileOptionsE+42)
08-28 22:36:38.582  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #12 pc 000c3ce1  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (android_main+120)
08-28 22:36:38.582  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #13 pc 000d1219  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so
08-28 22:36:38.583  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #14 pc 000475c3  /system/lib/libc.so (_ZL15__pthread_startPv+22)
08-28 22:36:38.583  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #15 pc 0001a115  /system/lib/libc.so (__start_thread+6)
08-28 22:36:39.012  5487  5487 E         : debuggerd: failed to kill process 5450: No such process
08-28 22:36:39.014   183   183 W         : debuggerd: resuming target 5450
```

There are not any crashes if the shader has compilation error: program just prints the compilation error message. Visual Studio shows segmentation fault error. 
If I write without CompileGlslToSpvAssembly and try just to use CompileGlslToSpv then I got segmentation fault error on vulkan shader module creation without anything in logcat.

I tried to use:

1. the latest shaderc code from github repository builded by ndk-buld from NDK r13b, r14b, r15b from command line ( also with linking the ndk directory in Visual Studio parameters )
2. shaderc provided in third party subdirectory of ndk r13b and r14b. Bulding as shown in ndk faq:

   Ndk_path/ndk-build.cmd" -B NDK_PROJECT_PATH=. APP_BULD_SCRIPT=Android.mk 
   APP_STL=gnustl_static APP_ABI=armeabi-v7a APP_PLATFORM=android-24 
   ANDROID_CPP_FEATURES="exceptions" libshaderc_combined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like the issue here is that the Vulkan Validation layers, specifically `libVkLayer_core_validation.so` is exporting `spvBinaryParse` from its internal version of spirv-tools. This conflicts with the version that shaderc was built with.

```
08-28 22:36:38.579  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #01 pc 0017b3b9  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZN8libspirv16DiagnosticStreamD2Ev+84)
08-28 22:36:38.579  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #02 pc 00159a2d  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libVkLayer_core_validation.so (spvBinaryParse+5248)
08-28 22:36:38.580  5487  5487 F DEBUG   :     #03 pc 00194065  /data/app/com.AndroidEngine-1/lib/arm/libAndroidEngine.so (_ZN8libspirv18FriendlyNameMapperC1EPK13spv_context_tPKjj+124)
```

A solution to this would be to not include the validation layers in your apk. However this of course means that you don't get validation.

It looks like this has been fixed in the official repository.
https://github.com/KhronosGroup/Vulkan-LoaderAndValidationLayers

The binaries in the NDK appear to be older, but you should be able to build new ones from source.

Comment: Thank you very much! It works well now. Does it mean that there is no way to use validation layers with runtime shader compilation? At least at the moment?